# how to load files into AudioSegment.from_file

Tags: python-3.x, filesystems, pyaudio

I am trying to make a python script which can convert a file from 'm4a' to a '.wav' however it is not able to find the files, returning "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified" every time.

Paths[0] include the full path of the file in question

```
m4a_file = paths[0]

wav_filename = filename + ".wav"
#track = AudioSegment.from_file(m4a_file,  format= 'm4a')
track = AudioSegment.from_file(file = relative_path,
                               format = 'm4a')
file_handle = track.export(wav_filename, format='wav')
```

// I've tried to

I've given both relative and full path for the file in question

'c:\Users\user\....\Workspace\Pollux\my_file.m4a'
and
'my_file.m4a'

Answer (score 0):

Try using \\ instead of \ in the path
like C:\\User\\Path\\etc.m4a

Something like this should work for multiple files in a folder (assuming all the files in the folder are m4a)

```
from os import listdir
from pydub import AudioSegment

relative_path = "C:\\Users\\PathTom4aFiles" #Save the path to the audio
audio_files = listdir("C:\\Users\\PathTom4aFiles") # Loading all filenames in the folder to a list

# And then adding lines below inside a loop if needed
track = AudioSegment.from_file(file = relative_path+"\\"+audio_files[0],format = 'm4a')
track.export(audio_files[0].replace("m4a","wav"), format='wav')
```